# No consigo ejecutar Tensor Flow

Tags: redes-neuronales, tensorflow

Quiero entrenar mi propia red neuronal pero no consigo ejecutar ni el ejemplo. Ejecuto el siguiente comando:

```
python classify_image.py
```

Y me sale lo siguiente:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "classify_image.py", line
>   46, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf   File "/Users/Yitman/TensorFlow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import *   File "/Users/Yitman/TensorFlow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py",
>   line 72, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/Yitman/TensorFlow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py",
>   line 61, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "/Users/Yitman/TensorFlow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()   File "/Users/Yitman/TensorFlow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description) ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Users/Yitman/TensorFlow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so,
>   10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Users/Yitman/TensorFlow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
>   Reason: image not found
>   Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>   See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

Básicamente, entiendo que no encuentra el archivo, pero este esta ahí. ¿Alguien lo ha ejecutado satisfactoriamente y me puede indicar los pasos correctos? También quiero entrenar la red neuronal con mis propias imágenes, ¿cómo procedo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Me pasó algo similar en mac.

Ejecuta lo siguiente.

`$ which python`

Si la salida no es /usr/local/bin/python entonces haz lo siguiente.

`$ brew install python`
`$ brew linkapps python`
`$ which python`

Deberías tener la siguiente salida.
/usr/local/bin/python

Ahora instala tensorflow
`$ pip install tensorflow`

Para ver que todo está bien:
`$ python
import tensorflow as tf`

Pienso que debería funcionar, yo lo solucioné así.